# Is there a way to cancel Airflow dag run while it is being executed?

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to find a way to cancel Airflow dag run while it is being executed. (whichever task it is at that moment). I wonder if I can set the status to "failed" while dag is running?

Answer (score 0):

yes , you can just click on task that is running and mark as failed. This will fail all downstream tasks and then DAG eventually

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to cancel it programmatically and not from the UI? I would like to automate the process.